Failed to Create the Storage area Association when trying to setup Shadow Copies
Been having some issues with a Windows Server 2022 VM that had Shadow Copies enabled.
E: Data
S: Copy
I had the shadow copy go to the S:
After some issue, I did a VM restore and deleted the S:
Disabled Shadow Copies
Then edited the VM and added a new volume (D:)
Trying to reconfigure E: to shadow Copy to D:
Get the following error.
Failed to create the storage area association.
Error 0x8004231d: The specified shadow copy association is in use and so can't be deleted.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Resolved it by using the command line and specifying shadow copies storage amount to be a little over 15%.  For whatever reason the GUI wouldn't take it.
